# C programming on fgets() function characters limitation?

Tags: c, char, fgets

Sample code:

```
    int i;
    char word [10][15];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){

      fgets(word[i], 16, stdin);

    }
```

So I take in (at max) 10 string user inputs and the length of each string can't be over 15 characters long (hence 16 because of the `\n` stored at the last character place of the `fgets()` method, right?).

My problem is when I want to print out the words in words array. This happens:

Input:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

pqrstuvwxyz
```

I don't know why this is happening. It seems that `fgets()` doesn't stop after taking in 15 characters of an input.

EDIT:

```
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      printf("%s", word[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Can I please see your entire code, including the code you use to print out the `word` array? It's hard to work with only a part of your code.

Comment: Ok I will edit Sorry

Comment: Also, your syntax is incorrect (`char[10][15] word;` is not correct C syntax). This code will not compile. Please post the actual code.

Comment: I will try that immediately, but I read somewhere that in order to take in n characters, that has to be set n + 1? I probably read that wrong  Also I edited that part. Sorry about that

Comment: I changed the fgets to fgets(words[i], 15, stdin), but now it only takes in 14 characters. How to store 15 characters then? EDIT: Oh I see thank you

Comment: Got it. If you want to put that as the answer, I can close this question ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that in the C programming language, every string is terminated with a trailing `\0` byte. The `fgets` function reads at most one less character than you allow it to write to the buffer, so it can terminate the string in the buffer with a `\0` byte. Now, in your code you allow `fgets` to write one byte more into `word` than each `char[15]` in `word` has. Initially, the `word` array looks like this:

```
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ...
^                             ^                             ^
word[0]                       word[1]                       word[2]
```

where `?` stands for an undefined value. After your code invokes `fgets` for the first time, `words` looks like this:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o \0? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ...
^                             ^                             ^
word[0]                       word[1]                       word[2]
```

Observe that `fgets` wrote one more byte than there is space in `words[0]`, so it wrote into space that belongs to `word[1]`. Yet, if you were to print out the content of `word[0]` with `printf`, the string `abcdefghijklmno` would be printed as `printf` prints until it encounters a `\0` byte. Now see what `word` looks like after the second call to `fgets`:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z \n\0? ? ? ? ? ? ...
^                             ^                             ^
word[0]                       word[1]                       word[2]
```

In this invocation, `fgets` does not write beyond the end of `word[1]` because it encounters a newline (`\n`) byte before. Observe that the trailing `\0` byte of the string in `word[0]` has been overwritten because that string went into the memory region occupied by `word[1]`.

Now what happens if you print? The first call to `printf` starts to print beginning with the `a` until it encounters a `\0` character. This leads to the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n` being printed as there is no `\0` byte after the `o` left. The second invocation of `printf` starts where `word[1]` begins, at the `p` until it sees a `\0`, leading to `pqrstuvwxyz\n` be printed.

Now how do you fix this? Either make each string in your array one longer or let `fgets` only read `15` instead of `16` characters.